# Invoice Date to Shipment Transactional Email

Tags: transactional-mail, shipment

I need your help please. I couldn't find answer from anywhere on how to insert an Invoice Date to Shipment transactional e-mail.

I tried to use the {{var invoice.created_at}}  but it gives me a blank result. i.e. http://prntscr.com/5cgoub

I can understand that the Invoice template doesn't have an Invoice date inserted, but I'm hoping that this is possible via a custom variable?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean the shipment email or invoice emails?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am confused by your question the shipment emails do not contain the invoice information.

During the sendEmail function in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment` you can see what objects are added to the email for use.

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $order,
        'shipment'     => $this,
        'comment'      => $comment,
        'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    )
);
```

Technically you can use the order object and try to load the invoice and then get the date but I think an order could technically have multiple invoices so I wonder if your thinking is not a bit flawed here.